# PHP Sort in a loop

Tags: php

I have the following loop that displays a series of items/posts that each contain a unique numerical catalog number:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  ?>
 <li>
 <?php echo $catalogNumber; ?>
 </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I would like to sort this list by the numerical value stored in $catalogNumber but not certain how to incorporate it into the existing loop.

Comment: And what's the value within  `$catalogNumber`. Post the array structure

Comment: The value in $catalognumber is a numerical value.

Comment: Post it over here and also  the expected output

Comment: is $catalogNumber is sorted already? what is the link between $items and   $catalogNumber ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) which sort the array by the key.

```
ksort ($items);
//Loop here.
```

> Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is
>   useful mainly for associative arrays.

**Ignore the following as it relates to a one dimensional array and won't fit to your case.**

Since it's a numerical value, you can simply use the [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function.

> This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to
>   highest when this function has completed.

In case you want to order to be from the highest to lowest simply use `rsort` as [@Uchiha suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001757/php-sort-in-a-loop#comment50031533_31001890).

Comment: _In case you want to order to be from the highest to lowest simply use array_reverse after using the sort function._ **What about** [**rsort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) +1

Comment: You're right. Anyway - I've changed the answer as it didn't take in account that the OP want the array to be sorted by the key of the array.

Comment: Good one but can't say anything about the OPs answer as the code within OPs question doesn't relevant to anything

Comment: Jut s a little bit more complicated than I was hoping. But i do thank you all for your input. I'll continue to soldier through this issue and post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your array using usort function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or asort function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) before this loop.